# Is there a concrete description of $\Theta_{\mathrm{sing}}$ for a generic curve of genus $6$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, jacobians

If $C$ is a generic curve of genus $6$, then $\Theta_{\mathrm{sing}}$ is a smooth surface. Can anyone give me a reference or a hint as to what that surface might be. What are the numerical characteristics of this surface? It has an involution. What is the quotient of this surface? How is this surface related to the curve $C$? I would ideally like information along the lines of the genus $5$ case in which case $\Theta_{\mathrm{sing}}$ is a double cover of a curve of genus $6$ and the Prym of this cover is the original $C$. In case it helps, the inverse image of $\Theta_{\mathrm{sing}}$ in $\mathrm{Sym}^5(C)$ is a three-fold which is determinantal.

Comment: You probably already know this, but for the benefit of others I point out that the non-generic cases are described on page 211 of the book "Geometry of Algebraic Curves" by Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths and Harris. One can get some information about the surface, like the dimension of the cohomology groups of the structure sheaf, from these descriptions using degeneration and the semi-continuity theorem.

Comment: @ulrich . I am travelling and don't have my copy of ACGH handy, but does it discuss genus 6 or genus 5 curves ?

Comment: @ulrich p.211 does indeed discuss two cases where the surface isn't smooth.  I think the case of a plane quintic is interesting.  I have never been able to see how to go from that case to the generic case.  If you have more thoughts on that, I would love to hear them.

Comment: In the paper of Arbarello and Harris, on Canonical curves and quadrics of rank 4, pp 171-174 (footnote), there is a description of this surface as an etale double cover of one of the 6 components of the surface of quadrics of rank 4 in P^5 containing the canonical model of the genus 6 curve C, if I understood correctly.  The other 5 components are all 2-planes.  Maybe this will help.  I.e. the curve C lies on a Veronese surface which lies on five 2 planes of rank 4 quadrics, and then there is another component of such quadrics through C not containing the Veronese.

Comment: I'm not sure if @roysmith's comment answered your question. In any case, for a plane quintic the surface $X$ is $C \times C$ with the diagonal blown down. Denoting the blow down morphism by $p$, one sees using the theorem on formal functions that $R^1 p_* \mathcal{O}_{C \times C}$ is is $7$-dimensional ($g+1$ for general $g>1$). One also sees that $h^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = 6$ since line bundles on $X$ are line bundles on $C \times C$ trivial on the diagonal.

Comment: Using the fact that one knows the cohomology of the structure sheaf for $C \times C$, one sees that there is a non-trivial differential in the Leray spectral sequence for $p$, and then one gets that $h^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = h^2(C \times C, \mathcal{O}_{C \times C}) + 1 = 37$. The semincontinuity theorem then implies that the corresponding cohomology groups for the surface associated to the generic curve have the same dimension (since the $h^1$ is at least $6$).

Comment: @roy smith, @ ulrich.  Thanks for the comments.  I've just got the paper and I am trying to digest it.  I will reply more after that.  I am trying to write down the semi-continuity argument too.  Thanks to both of you for your comments.

Comment: In connection with ulrich's nice comment see exercise VI.B1, ACGH p. 264.  Or as you no doubt see, (but I had forgotten), if L = g(2,5) is the plane quintic line bundle on C then sing(Theta) is the image of CxC under (p,q)-->L-p+q.

Comment: @ulrich- I see says the blind man.  I finally see that by semicontinuity one knows p_g on the generic curve from the comments you give on p_g and the fact that 6 is both an upper and lower bound for q.  That says what the numerical invariants are.  I suspect there is more to be said, even in the non-generic case, about the structure of the singular locus.  On p.274, acgh enumerates the different structures on the singular locus for g=5.  It depends on more that just the coarse fact of what the most special linear system is that exists on the curve.

Comment: @ roy smith- still working the beautiful paper by Arborello and Harris.

Comment: @ both of you- thanks for your helpful comments.

Comment: @aginensky: I should have said that to actually justify my comment one has to compute the scheme theoretic structure of the singular locus in the case of the plane quintic and show that it is just the reduced structure. I have not done this myself.

Comment: Nor have I yet :).